# D'où vient « Mais où est donc Ornicar ? » ?

Tags: histoire, conjonctions, apprentissage, coordination

[*Ornicar*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2817777%29_Ornicar) est un astéroïde nommé ainsi par l'astronome Français M. Alain Maury en mémoire de la célèbre formule mnémotechnique « *Mais où est donc Ornicar ?* »<sup>1</sup> servant à apprendre les [conjonctions de coordination](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjonction_de_coordination). On a donc maintenant la réponse à cette question.

À l'*Académie française*, on a rédigé un [billet](http://academie-francaise.fr/mais-ou-est-donc-ornicar) là-dessus. On conclut en disant :

> Cet Ornicar n’était donc pas, comme on aurait pu le croire, un
>   lointain cousin des [Barca](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilisation_carthaginoise), [Hamilcar](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilcar_Barca) ou [Bomilcar](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bomilcar), qui furent parents
>   d’[Hannibal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_Barca), ni d’un éventuel prétendant au trône d’[Ottokar](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Sceptre_d'Ottokar), dont Hergé
>   nous a conté l’histoire, si le bon roi Muskar XII était venu à
>   abdiquer.

---

Je n'entretenais pas de telles croyances au moment où ces choses m'ont été enseignées, d'où mes questions, essentiellement sur l'étymologie de la formule :

- Quand et dans quelle grammaire ou instrument didactique emploie-t-on
  pour la première fois la formule mnémotechnique « *Mais où est donc
  Ornicar ?* » ?
- Est-ce une influence *hellénisante*<sup>2</sup> (l'histoire de [Carthage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthage) racontée par les Grecs puis enseignée en France, l'enseignement du latin/grec, etc.) qui explique ce choix (de nom, ultimement de toute la formule) ; n'a-t-on jamais expliqué pourquoi on avait choisi *Ornicar/or-ni-car*, plutôt qu'un(e) autre nom/autre combinaison des trois conjonctions ?
- La formule consacrée est-elle la formule la plus intéressante/utile (mnémotechnique) qu'on puisse générer
  avec les conjonctions : *mais-ou-et-donc-or-ni-car* ?

---

<sub>**1.** On note qu'on a opté au Québec pour « [Carnior](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mais_o%C3%B9_est_donc_Ornicar_%3F) » (l'article Wikipédia donne aussi la majuscule) ; quelqu'un aurait pu bien naïvement penser que c'était une référence à *carnivore* (*mais où est donc / carni(v)or(e)* ) pour ensuite ne plus jamais se poser la question ; on n'aura peut-être même jamais entendu « *Ornicar* » !</sub>
<sub>**2.** Par exemple, à l'âge de 10 ans (donc autour de 1864), Arthur Rimbaud s'insurge de devoir apprendre le latin et le grec : « *Que m'importe à moi qu'Alexandre ait été célèbre? Que m'importe... Que sait-on si les latins ont existé? C'est peut-être quelque langue forgée; et quand même ils auraient existé, qu'ils me laissent rentier et conservent leur langue pour eux. Quel mal leur ai-je fait pour qu'ils me flanquent au supplice? Passons au grec... Cette sale langue n'est parlée par personne, personne au monde!...*» (A. Rimbaud, [*Premières proses*](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-101484&M=notice)).</sub>

Comment: Le billet de l'Académie est très malicieux. *Ornicar* et *Carni[v]or[e]* semblent être deux moyens mnémotechniques très efficaces, les autres possibilités n'ont ni cette fluidité, ni cette puissance de jeu sur les mots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le "mais ou(ù) e(s)t donc" a un sens **et** est donc indiscutable. Heureusement, puisque cela divise par 840 le nombre de possibilités.

**Mais** il n'existe pas de nom commun réalisable avec les trois conjonctions restantes, quelle que soit leur combinaison.

**Or**, les syllabes se terminant par un "r" s'enchainent assez mal.

**Ni** orcar, **ni** caror ne sont très fluides.

Seuls Ornicar **ou** Carnior permettent de placer un "ni" au milieu.

**Donc** ils sont plus faciles à prononcer et ainsi à mémoriser.

Personnellement, je préfère Ornicar **car** le jeu de mot avec carnivore appelle un article qui n'est pas dans la phrase "Mais où est donc (le) carni(v)ore ? Il m'est toutefois difficile d'être objectif tant cette phrase est ancrée dans mon crâne.

Comment: j'ai mentionné mon manque d'objectivité tant Ornicar sonne juste après l'avoir répété des centaines (milliers) de fois. Pour l'article (ou le déterminant), on a une présence/absence qui brise le rythme de la phrase, alors que ou et où ont exactement la même prononciation, et que "et" ->é et "est" ->è sont très proche. Je pense que la présence absence est une source de confusion possible pour un enfant qui apprend les conjonctions. Avec "Mais où est donc ce carnivore?", l'enfant pourrait croire que "se" est une conjonction de coordination.

Comment: pour les math, le nombre de combinaisons possibles est la factorielle du nombre de syllabes. 2*3*4*5*6*7 = 5040. En ne comptant que les combinaison de or-ni-car, il n'y a plus que 6 possibilités (840 fois moins)

Comment: je traite de car-or-ni dans ma quatrième ligne. C'est une des possibilités à partir de "caror".

Comment: Ceci étant dit, je répète qu'il n'y a rien d'indiscutable. Je ne suis pas un spécialiste de la mémoire. Je sais juste qu'une chanson se retient plus facilement qu'un texte, et que donc la fluidité joue un rôle pour la mémorisation.

Comment: La réponse est logique et bien écrite, mais la question principale, à savoir quand la phrase mnémotechnique a été forgée, et par qui, reste entière...

Answer (score 1):

La réponse de radouxju me parait tout à fait valide, mais je voudrais la complémenter.

L'enchainement "io" de "ni-or" implique une diphtongue, qui est légèrement plus difficile à prononcer (de mon point de vue français métropolitain) qu'un enchainement standard de syllabes avec alternance voyelles/consonne ("ni - car"). On aurait tendance à l'abréger en une syllabe "gnor" ce qui n'aide pas à la mémorisation.

Je suppose que les Québécois ont moins de difficultés pour les diphtongues, ce qui explique qu'ils n'ont pas rechigné à utiliser "car-ni-or", mais ce n'est que pure spéculation.

De même placer "car" devant "or" incite à considérer le "r" final comme le début de la prochaine syllabe (naturellement on découpe en "ca-ror" et pas "car-or")

Comment: Merci, spéculation intéressante ! Je diphtongue _Dior_, wikipédia indique djɔːʁ ; ça fait di-or ou d-yor ça ? Ouais peut-être qu'on gère la diphtongue différemment. Je ne comprends que très peu la phonétique, souvent rien ne cadre avec ma perception de ma prononciation, c'est encore pire en anglais, où par ailleurs je ne suis plus un débutant depuis longtemps, alors que j'ai l'impression que tout est une diphtongue et parfois je me demande comment écrire tel mot avec l'IPA et je suis encore moins capable qu'en français, je dois forcément regarder au lexique.

Comment: Parmis les gens que je fréquente tout le monde dit "d'yor" en une seule syllabe, sauf deux personnes (une venant de la région alsacienne, une autre du Québec) qui découpent toutes les diphtongues (li-on, vi-olons...). Je ne sais pas si il s'agit d'un trait spécifique à ces personnes ou si c'est plus généralisé.

Comment: Dans la question je lis *A apprendre les conjonctions de coordination les plus connues* : y en aurait il d autres ?

Comment: @EmmanuelBRUNO Il y a d'autres coordonnants, mais les conjonctions de coordination, c'est une liste limitative en effet. On corrige. Merci !